# Simplifying trigonometric expressions

Tags: trigonometry

Please simplify and give a step process. No calculators of course.

$$\tan^{-1}\left[\cot\left(\frac{π}{8}\right)\right]$$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\tan^{-1}(\tan\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\dfrac{\pi}{8})$.

Comment: **Hint:**

$\cot(\alpha)=\tan(\tfrac{\pi}2-\alpha)$

Comment: the result should be $$\frac{3\pi}{8}$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

We have, for $x>0$

$$\arctan(x)+\arctan(\frac{1}{x})=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

thus

$$\arctan(cotan(\frac{\pi}{8}))=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{8}=\frac{3\pi}{8}$$

Answer (score 0):

***Formulas that we will use:***

$cot\theta=\frac{1}{tan\theta}$

$tan(\frac{\theta}{2})=\frac{1-cos\theta}{sin\theta}=\frac{sin\theta}{1+cos\theta}$

***By using the formulas we will get:***

$tan^{-1}[cot(\frac{\pi}{8})]
=tan^{-1}[\frac{1}{tan(\frac{\pi}{8})}]
=tan^{-1}[\frac{1}{tan(\frac{\pi}{4}\times\frac{1}{2})}]
=tan^{-1}[\frac{1}{tan(\frac{\pi/4}{2})}]
\\
=tan^{-1}[\frac{1}{\frac{sin(\frac{\pi}{4})}{1+cos(\frac{\pi}{4})}}]
=tan^{-1}[\frac{1}{\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}}]
=tan^{-1}[\frac{1}{\frac{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}{1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}}]
=tan^{-1}[\frac{1}{\frac{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}{\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{2}}}]
\\
=tan^{-1}[\frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\times\frac{2}{2+\sqrt{2}}}]
=tan^{-1}[\frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2+\sqrt{2}}}]
=tan^{-1}[\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}]
=tan^{-1}[\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\times\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2-\sqrt{2}}]
\\
=tan^{-1}[\frac{(2+\sqrt{2})(2-\sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{2}(2-\sqrt{2})}]
=tan^{-1}[\frac{4-2\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{2}-2}{2\sqrt{2}-2}]
=tan^{-1}[\frac{2}{2\sqrt{2}-2}]
\\
=tan^{-1}[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-1}]
=tan^{-1}[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-1}\times\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{\sqrt{2}+1}]
=tan^{-1}[\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{(\sqrt{2}-1)(\sqrt{2}+1)}]
\\
=tan^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{2+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}-1})
=tan^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{1})
=tan^{-1}(\sqrt{2}+1)
\\
=arctan(\sqrt{2}+1)$